# Playing games on VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have set up a WinXP VM on an Ubuntu host and have assigned 2 gig RAM to the guest. Now I am trying to play a game on the VM. I have enabled 3D acceleration in Virtualbox settings. The specs of the VM fulfil the minimum system requirements of the game. But the game sort of freezes and then crashes just after starting it. My PC is dual-booted with Windows, and this game runs fine there, but I usually use Linux and hardly ever use Windows. I don't wanna reboot my PC everytime I want to play a game. Is there any way to make this work in a VM?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is a native linux version of this game. Any particular reason why you would not try that?

Comment: According to the [game webpage](http://store.steampowered.com/app/230290/), that game is available for SteamPlay. Why not go with that?

Comment: Oops, wasn't aware of that.. Will try that.

Comment: Another thing: you tagged your question with VMWare, but refer to VirtualBox in the text. You better clarify that.

Comment: Done.. But some games like NFS aren't available on Linux, can I play those in virtualbox?

Comment: Yes, VirtualBox has supported OpenGL for a number of years now. Your issue is either specific to that programme or to your hardware.